# how to dynamically change color of font/background

Tags: angular

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({

  selector: '[myHighlighter]'
})
export class Highlight {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }


  @Input('myHighlighter') 
  highlightColor: string;


  @HostListener('mouseenter') 
  onMouseEnter() {
    this.highlight( this.highlightColor || 'red');
  }


  @HostListener('mouseleave') 
  onMouseLeave() {
    this.highlight(null);
  }

  private highlight(color: string) {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
}
```

How do I change the directive above so that the user can dynamically change the font and highlight color? I am guessing an input would be the best way for the user to enter in the desired color but i am unsure of the syntax.

Comment: Take a look at [this section](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#pass-values-into-the-directive-with-an-input-data-binding) of the Angular documentation.

Comment: so you're trying to read from an input or a binded value and use that value as the color?  i'm a little confused

Answer (score 0):

You already had created the directive for highlight, if you want to pass dynamic data then you can simply pass it as input.

ex :

```
<input type="text" #color ngModel /> . <!-- use the color reference to pass to directive -->

<div [myHighlighter]="color.value"> Some text to highlight </div>
```

Similarly you can implement for font-size.

Here is working demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzikhx